# What does setDrawRange do? in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, data-visualization

I have been studying a three.js code.

While reading through the code and the documentation, 
there is one thing i can't get.

in this code.
http://jsfiddle.net/w67tzfhx/

there is a code as below.

```
function init(){

    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    var positions = new Float32Array(MAX_POINTS*3);
        geometry.addAttribute('position',new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions,3))

        drawCount =2;
        geometry.setDrawRange(0,drawCount );

        mat =  new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, linewidth: 2 } );

        line= new THREE.Line(geometry, mat)

        scene.add(line)

        updatePositions();

}
```

what is setDrawRange?
and what does drawCount do there?

the official document says

> .setDrawRange ( start : Integer, count : Integer ) : null Set the
>   .drawRange property. For non-indexed BufferGeometry, count is the
>   number of vertices to render. For indexed BufferGeometry, count is the
>   number of indices to render.

which I don't get at all.

Can anyone help me explaing what it is?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Your Geometry has a number of vertices. For example a cube has at least 36 (6 for each of the 6 sides because each side needs 2 triangles to make a rectangle and each triangle needs 3 vertices). By default three would draw all 36. To draw just first 6 you'd call `setDrawRange(0, 6)`. To draw the last 6 you'd call `setDrawRange(30, 6)`.  To draw all 36 of them you'd call `setDrawRange(0, 36)`

Vertices can be indexed or non-indexed. If they are indexed it just means there is a level of indirection in the data. Instead of `setDrawRange(0, 6)` referring to the first 6 vertices, it instead refers to the first 6 indices which in turn refer to 6 vertices (some may be repeated if the indices repeat).

It's not common to use `setDrawRange` but one use case, say you want draw a bunch of lines. Instead of making lots of individual line objects you just make one geometry with space for a bunch of lines (say 1000 lines which is 2000 vertices). You then add lines to the geometry as you need them and tell three to only draw the first N lines by calling `setDrawRange(0, numLines * 2)`  (2 vertices per line)

You can learn more about Geometry [here](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-custom-geometry.html) and [here](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-custom-buffergeometry.html)